# why my Vagrantfile run provision after each vm created when I was trying to make ti only run after all vm created

Tags: vagrant

I have a Vagrantfile as below, and I wish to run ansible provision only one time after all vm are created, but actually it runs each time after a vm created, I do not know why? How can I make the ansible provision run only once? thanks in advance.

```
IMAGE_NAME = "bento/debian-10.5"
N = 2

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    (1..N).each do |i|
        config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
            node.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
            node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.#{10 + i}"
            node.vm.hostname = "node-#{i}"
        end
        
        if i == N 
            # only run provision after all vm created
            config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
                ansible.playbook = "ansible/site.yml"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I tried to move the config.vm.provision code inside the if condition to config.vm.define block, it still runs ansible provision each time after a vm created

```
    (1..N).each do |i|
        config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
            node.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
            node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.#{10 + i}"
            node.vm.hostname = "node-#{i}"
        
            if i == N 
                # only run provision after all vm created
                config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
                    ansible.playbook = "ansible/site.yml"
                end
            end
        end
    end
```